# i want to delete the details on regex

Tags: regex

I have a lot of accounts, and I want to remove all the details

```
example1@gmail.com | example1 | Personal[US] | Verified | | No SMART | No Bank | No Card | Example1 | Example2 | Example3 | Checked on https://www.example.com at 1:43 pm - September 6, 2015
example2@gmail.com | example2 | Personal[US] | Verified | | No SMART  | No Bank | No Card | Example1 | Example2 | Example3 | Checked on https://www.example.com at 5:33 pm - September 6, 2015
example3@gmail.com | example3 | Personal[US] | Unverified | | No SMART | No Bank | No Card | Example1 | Example2 | Example3 | Checked on https://www.example.com at 5:35 pm - September 6, 2015
```

and i want to delete

like this

```
example1@gmail.com|example1
example2@gmail.com|example2
example3@gmail.com|example3
```

question , whats code on regular expression to mass delete?

Comment: What is the programming language? Regex itself does not delete, it matches, or fails to match some text.

Comment: like this :3 https://regex101.com/r/lK2oE3/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following replacement:

Regex:

```
^([^|]*?)\s*\|\s*([^|]*).*
```

Replacement:

```
\1|\2
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT3qP6/1)

The regex will match the

- `^` - start of string
- `([^|]*?)` - 0 or more characters other than `|` as few as possible (Group 1 - `\1`)
- `\s*\|\s*` - optional whitespace symbols, `|`, and again optional whitespace symbols
- `([^|]*)`  - 0 or more characters other than `|` (Group 2 - `\2`)
- `.*` - 0 or more symbols other than newline

With the back-references to the captured groups, we get our replacement string.